# HTML5 attribute value normalization

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, normalization

In XML whitespace in attributes values are [normalized to spaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize). Thus `test="foo#xD#xAbar"` (with a CRLF between `foo` and `bar`) is normalized to `test="foo bar"` upon parsing.

But does attribute normalization happen with HTML as well—specifically HTML5? The [HTML 5.2 spec on attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#element-definitions-attributes) doesn't mention it. A search if `html5 normalization of attribute values` on the web surprisingly did not immediately reveal any discussion on the matter.

I found an [email on a W3C mailing list](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-comments/2011Aug/0049.html) seeming to state that HTML4 normalized attribute values, but that HTML5 does *not*. It pointed to W3C HTML5 [Bug 13709](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=13709) from 2011, which provided no additional information. I also found W3C [ISSUE-87](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/tracker/issues/87); this seems to have been [closed with prejudice](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2010Jan/0064.html) after little to no discussion.

Let me give you an example of application. I have several HTML5 CSS classes that begin with `prefix-`, including (among others) `prefix-foo` and `prefix-bar`. I want to select element `example` but only if it does *not* contain a class starting with `prefix-`—sort of a combination of the `|=` and the `~=` attribute selectors.

```html
<example class="select">this will be blue</example>
<example class="do-not-select prefix-foo">this should not be blue</example>
<example class="prefix-bar do-not-select">this should not be blue</example>
<example class="select-prefix-is-not-a-prefix">but this <em>should</em> be blue</example>
```

Note that the last example has a `prefix-` substring, but not as a CSS class token prefix.

I came up with the following selector, which works on the above examples:

```css
example:not([class^="prefix-"]):not([class*=" prefix-"]):
  background-color: blue;
;
```

My worry is that if the source uses whitespace other than a space whether the selector will still work. For example:

```html
<example class="do-not-select


prefix-foo">this should not be blue either</example>
```

Surprisingly this works, both on Firefox and Chrome. It would appear that the newline in the attribute source is getting normalized to a space in the DOM. Or maybe there is no normalization happening, but some CSS specification indicates that a space in an attribute selector should match any whitespace (i.e. the normalization is during matching not during parsing).

Now that I've explained my use case, let me simplify the test case. Take this CSS style:

```css
div[class*=" prefix-"] {
  background-color: green;
;
```

And take this HTML:

```html
<div class="select prefix-foo">this should be green</div>

<div class="select

prefix-foo">this should be green only if whitespace is normalized</div>
```

Both of those are showing green for me, both in Firefox and in Chrome.

The [HTML5 specification for `class`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-class) says that the value is [space-separated](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/infrastructure.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens), which includes any [space characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/infrastructure.html#space-characters) including tabs and newlines. It says nothing about normalization, though.

Could someone please explain, citing relevant authoritative specifications, whether HTML5 normalizes attribute values; and whether spaces in CSS attribute selectors match literally or match any whitespace?

Comment: To clarify, .select-prefix-is-not-a-prefix *should* be blue (as the name suggests), and is. But the example with the newlines in the class attribute also registers as blue in my tests. In CSS, whitespace normalization only takes place outside of strings.

Comment: Right, I was getting my "select" and "match" mixed up. Maybe I should have found a way for a simplified example without `not()`. (I was copying my particular use case.) I have now fixed the typo. Now, BoltClock, any ideas on the whitespace normalization? Your comment seemed to imply that there is CSS normalization of attributes—but the whole thrust of this question is: Is there indeed normalization, and if so, on what authority?

Comment: CSS does not normalize whitespace in strings in attribute values as far as I know. It will normalize line breaks in the source outside of strings unless you use escape sequences such as \a for line feeds. See https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#case-sensitive and https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters

Comment: Well then, BoltClock, if CSS does not normalize whitespace, then why is the class with line breaks currently being skipped as expected? The `:not([class*=" prefix-"])` should not work unless the line break is being normalized somewhere to be a space, correct? I'll add a simplified example in the question.

Comment: Ah, BoltClock, I found the problem. I can see why the newline example didn't work for you. My source file was (correctly) being interpreted as XHTML5, not HTML5. You were right: there seems to be no attribute normalization in HTML. (See my separate answer.) Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that my test file was an XHTML5 file and the browsers were following XML attribute normalization rules. When served as HTML5, no attribute normalization seems to occur.

My original test case was actually an XHTML5 file stored in e.g. `text.xhtml` and looked like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

…

<div class="select prefix-foo">this should be green</div>

<div class="select

prefix-foo">this should be green only if whitespace is normalized</div>
```

This is perfectly valid XHTML5. I'm using a static site generator which produces HTML5, but I had forgotten that my source was XHTML5. When I tested the file locally from the file system, both Firefox and Chrome were correctly recognizing the file as XML-based, and thereby applying XML attribute normalization rules.

When I ran my static site generator and served these files, without the XML declaration, as `text/html` files (HTML5), both Firefox and Chrome did *not* select the second `<div>`.

So it would appear that **HTML5 does not normalize whitespace in attributes**. My mistakenly thinking that this was happening stems from the fact that **I was inadvertently testing on XHTML5 files following XML normalization rules**.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I had used data:text/html,... in my tests - I should've figured the file type had to do with it (vs application/xhtml+xml). Thankfully, the bounty you placed was small and not entirely in vain ;)